# Xamarin.iOS Visual Studio Mac 2022 not show crash stacktrace

Tags: xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac

With the new Visual Studio Mac 2022 I can't see where my app crashes, instead with the old version of Visual Studio I can see the stacktrace.
Does anyone have a solution?

[Visual Studio 2019 Mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXT42.png)

[Visual Studio 2022 Mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJsRB.png)

Comment: did you try looking at the `Stack Trace` property of the exception object?

Comment: If i looking the ex.stacktrace i can see where crash but is not functional like the previous version

Comment: Help --> Report a Problem

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/XamariniOS-Visual-Studio-Mac-2022-not-s/10071822

Comment: Is there any update on this? It still seems not to work....

Comment: It’s still not working - on a totally new project. Clearly no-one at Microsoft actually uses VS2022 on a Mac!!